# jquery mobile form does not submit

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-mobile, submit

I would like to get some user data using a php form and store it in a mysql database , trouble is, the page simply refreshes when I submit the form.

Here is my php form:

```
<form id="companyform" name="companyform" method="post" action="index3.php" data-ajax="false">
<b>To enlist your business fill in the form below:</b>
<p>
<label for="name">Company Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="companyname" id="companyname"  data-mini="true"/>
</p>
<p>
<label for="name">Company Address:</label>
<input type="text" name="companynaddress" id="companynaddress"  data-mini="true"/>
</p>
<p>
<label for="textfield">Tel No.:</label>
<input type="text" name="tel" id="tel"  data-mini="true"/>
</p>
<p>
<label for="textfield">Fax No.:</label>
<input type="text" name="fax" id="fax"  data-mini="true"/>
</p>
<p>
<label for="textfield">Email:</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email"  data-mini="true"/>
</p>
<p>
<label for="textfield">Website Address:</label>
<input type="text" name="website" id="website"  data-mini="true"/>
</p>

<p>
<label for="textfield">Contact Person Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="contactname" id="contactname"  data-mini="true"/>
</p>

<p>
<label for="textfield">Contact Person Number:</label>
<input type="text" name="contactnumber" id="contactnumber"  data-mini="true"/>
</p>

<p>
<label for="textfield">Contact Person Email:</label>
<input type="text" name="contactemail" id="contactemail"  data-mini="true"/>
</p>

<p>
<input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</p>
</form>
```

and here is my database connection code:

```
<?php

if (array_key_exists('submit', $_POST)) {

$con = mysql_connect("host",    "user", "pass");

if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("botswanasearchdb", $con);

$companyname = $_POST['companyname'];
$companyaddress = $_POST['companyaddress'];
$tel = $_POST['tel'];
$fax = $_POST['fax'];
$emailid = $_POST['emailid'];
$website = $_POST['website'];
$contactname = $_POST['contactname'];
$contactnumber = $_POST['contactnumber'];
$contactemail = $_POST['contactemail'];

// prepare the SQL query
 $sql = "INSERT INTO businessuser (companyname, companyaddress, tel, fax, emailid,   website, contactname, contactnumber, contactemail) VALUES ('$companyname',   '$companyaddress', '$tel', '$fax', '$emailid', '$website', '$contactname', '$contactnumber', '$contactemail')";
mysql_close($con);
}

?>
```

Comment: How is this related to jquery(-mobile)? I don't see any javascript.

Comment: can you see some call on the webserver? Is there something in the log ?

Comment: You should remove your database string. I can connect to your database.

Comment: @jeroen i am using jquery only for the interface, but it seems to be hindering every form i try to submit.. is there any work around? When i submit, th page just refreshes itself

Comment: What does `index3.php` contain?

Comment: the form with the input fields

Comment: "it seems to be hindering every form i try to submit" So maybe show us the jQuery?

Comment: @Tom.. the jquery in the head just links to... 
 <script src="docs/_assets/js/jqm-docs.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.js"></script>

Answer (score 2):

This is your form tag:

```
<form id="companyform" name="companyform" method="post" action="index3.php" data-ajax="false">
```

So you are submitting the form to `index3.php` (the `action` attribute). According to your comment `index3.php` contains your form and that is why the form refreshes when you submit it. You are basically reloading your form on form submit.

You need to submit the form to your php script that contains the php code you posted.

**Edit:** If everything is on the same page, you can do something like:

```
if (array_key_exists('submit', $_POST))
{
  // your code

  // show thank you message
}
else
{
  // show form
}
```

**Another edit:** As you are using the deprecated `mysql_*` functions and not escaping the data, you have an sql injection whole and a `'` character in your data will break your query. You should switch to PDO / mysqli and prepared statements. And always add error handling.

Comment: @Isaac Martin Then it is doing everything it is supposed to be doing, it saves the information in the database and shows the form again. If you don't want to show the form, just put it in an `else` block, see my edit.

Comment: That part works well, the issue is that my database does not receive any info..it remains empty so i thought jqm was the culprit

Comment: @Isaac Martin You should describe better what the actual problem is.

Comment: Ok..sorry if was misleading. i thought jquery's ajax loading property was not allowing the user inputs to be saved in my db (even though i put the data-ajax=""false" property on my form).. its hard to ask a question when even i can't see the problem, which is my problem..thanks jeroen

Comment: @Isaac Martin I added some comments as to where your query is probably failing. You should always add error handling as well.